# Simultaneous equations with three parts

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

\begin{align*}
6a +24b +18c &= 168\\
8a +28b +22c &= 208\\
4a + 20b +20c &= 140
\end{align*}
I've tried doing this multiplying so they cancelled out but I've always gotten decimal point answers.   I know the answer but don't know how to get there $a= 10$, $b=3$, $c=2$.

Comment: Divide equation 1 by 6, divide equation 2 by 2, and divide equation 3 by 4 first. That would help a little.

Comment: Could you show us your work?

Answer (score 1):

From the  comment of  KittyL your system become:

$$
\begin{cases}
a+4b+3c=28\\
4a+14b+11c=104\\
a+5b+5c=35
\end{cases}
$$

Now: multiply the first equation by $4$ and subtract the second, then subtract the first equation from the third to obtain

$$
\begin{cases}
2b+c=8\\
b+2c=7\\
a+4b+3c=28
\end{cases}
$$

Multiplying the second by $2$ and subtracting the first you have:
$$
3c=6 \Rightarrow c=2 \Rightarrow b= 7-4=3 \Rightarrow a=....
$$

Answer (score 0):

The given equations are equivalent to:
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}6a+24b+18c &=& 168\\ 8a+28b+22c&=&208\\ 12b+18c&=&72\end{array}\right.$$
or to:

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}6a+12b &=& 96\\ 2a+4b+4c&=&40\\ 12b+18c&=&72\end{array}\right.$$
that reduces to:
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}a+2b &=& 16\\ a+2b+2c&=&20\\ 2b+3c&=&12\end{array}\right.$$
and subtracting the first equation from the second we get $c=2$, so $b=3$ and $a=10$ as wanted.